# Can't get precise nearby locations using Apple mapkit in switft 5 on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm not able to get precise nearby locations using Apple's `MapKit`. When I run a search I get results from something 3-4 miles away from the location.

What I've tried so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
          {
              locationManager = CLLocationManager()
              locationManager.delegate = self
              locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
              locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
              locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
          }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {

        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0001, longitudeDelta: 0.0001))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)

        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Restaurants"
        request.region = region

        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        self.lbl1.text = ""

        search.start { response, error in
            guard let response = response else {
                print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error").")
                return
            }

            for item in response.mapItems {
                self.lbl1.text = (item.name ?? "No name") + "\n" + (self.lbl1.text ?? "No Name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything else to do to make the results more accurate for the location?

Comment: I would completely separate your location manager from your UI from your data implementations. You've combined them all into one, it appears. The location manager, IMO, should be set up at app launch (like in the App Delegate) because it may take some time to get an accurate location. And the location manager should, IMO, do nothing more than update a property that a data method somewhere else reads from. And the UI that makes use of location should depend on the data method and nothing else to update itself. Separation of powers.

Comment: Don't forget, location manager delegates like this one can fire rapidly in succession. You definitely don't want it in control of your UI.